# Regular Expression for matching a single digital followed by a word exactly in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, scite

:Statement

Say we have following three records, and we just want to match the first one **only** -- exactly one digital followed by a specific word, what is the regular expression can be used to make it(in NotePad ++)?

1. 2Cups
2. 11Cups
3. 222Cups

The expressions I tried and their problems are:

- Proposal 1:\d{1}Cups

it will find the "1Cups" and "2Cups" substrings in the second and third record respectively, which is what we do not want here

- Proposal 2:[^0-9]+[0-9]Cups

same as the above

(PS: the records can be "XX 2Cups", "YY22Cups" and "XYZ 333Cups", i.e., no assumption on the position of the matchable parts)

Any suggestions?

:Reference

[1] The reg definition in NotePad++ (Same as SciTe)

As mentioned in [Searching for a complex Regular Expression to use with Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414112/searching-for-a-complex-regular-expression-to-use-with-notepad), it is: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html

[2] Matching exact number of digits

Here is an example: [regular expression to match exactly 5 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975644/regular-expression-to-match-exactly-5-digits).

However, we do not want to find the match-able substring in longer records here.

Answer (score 2):

If the string actually has the numbered sequence (1. 2Cups 2. 11Cups), you can use the white space that follows it:

```
\s\d{1}Cups
```

If there isn't the numbered list before, but the string will be at the beginning of the line, you can anchor it there:

```
^\d{1}Cups
```

Tested in Notepad++ v6.5.1 (Unicode).

Comment: was going to post it :D

Comment: Guys, I am really sorry for the confusion -- the digital can be in the  middle of a line, i.e., the records can be: "XXX 2Cups","Y22Cups" and "MM 333Cups"

Comment: The 'Statement' has been updated (Added the 'PS' part). Really sorry for the confusion, guys.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to match the digit only at the start of the string or if it has a space before it, so this would work:

```
(^|\b)\dCups
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wAg8D5ndrDbicESk)

Explanation:

- `(^|\b)` Match the start of the string or beginning of a word (technically, word break)
- `\d` Match a digit (`{1}` is redundant)
- `Cups` Match Cups

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
\b\dCups
```

If "Cups" must be a whole word (ie not matching `2Cupsizes`:

```
\b\dCups\b
```

Note that `\b` matches even if at start or end of input.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution:

1. Using `^\d{1}Cups` to match "Starting with one digital + Cups" cases, as suggested by Ken, Cottrell and Bohemian.
2. Using `[^\d]\dCups` to match other cases.

However, haven't found a solution using just one regex to solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
(?:^|\D)\dCups
```

This will match xCups only if there aren't digit before.